# Is the file "my.ini" in the wrong place?

Tags: mysql

In the WorkBench when I click on the Options File it says it can't find "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\my.ini"

I don't even have version 5.0 on the machine, I've only installed versions 5.6 and 5.7 of the server.

However there is a my.ini in "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini".

If I just copy over the file I'm assuming that having two my.ini files will be confusing for the server.  Or will they?  And why is the WorkBench looking in the wrong place for this file?

Could this be why all login's except root have suddenly started to fail?

Comment: You can copy the ini file as much as you want. That will be no problem. The other odds are indeed a problem and you are better off answering those questions, instead of just copying the ini file. To me it sounds like you accidentally updated from 5.0 to 5.5 or had both installed and accidentally removed 5.0?! But the last time I've used Workbench was years ago, so I cannot provide detailed help...

Comment: Im glad it work. Please set my answer as correct instead of replying that the soltution was good. This is to ensure the quality of the posts are high! Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Connection settings. Right click on the connection adn select Edit Connections so you end up in Manage connections.

There is a tab called System Profile. Make sure that the path for **Configuration file** here is to the correct ini file. In your case the path should most likley be `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini`

[image]