# Different config in MySQL and Workbench

Tags: mysql, configuration, character-encoding, mysql-workbench

When connect to remote DB and get encoding config get this:
in windows command line:

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                            |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | cp1251                           |
| character_set_connection | cp1251                           |
| character_set_database   | latin1                           |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                           |
| character_set_results    | cp1251                           |
| character_set_server     | latin1                           |
| character_set_system     | utf8                             |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but in workbench:

```
character_set_client, utf8
character_set_connection, utf8
character_set_database, latin1
character_set_filesystem, binary
character_set_results, utf8
character_set_server, latin1
character_set_system, utf8
character_sets_dir, /usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/
```

I think workbench has own configuration file, but i can't find it. If I'm wrong, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what your question is, but I assume you wonder why certain character sets are different comparing the command line client and MySQL Workbench.

If you look closer you will see the only differences are those that affect the client (resultset, client + connection charsets). So, it's quite obvious these are configured by the clients. They configure those values as they need it. So much to your (implied) question.

A word about why MySQL Workbench chooses utf8 and cannot be changed: using a Unicode encoding all the time ensure as few as possible conversion problems. If you have text in your tables with any other encoding than what the connection or resultset use, you have to convert between those encodings. This is often not possible without losing information. By having utf8 in use in all relevant places we minimize this risk.

Comment: Is there any reasons utf8mb4 is not used by default instead? I'm not sure I understand why MySQL's UTF8 doesn't seem to support 4 bytes character in the first place...

Comment: The original utf-8 encoding in MySQL only used 3 bytes max, to store values. WB uses that because that was the best choice at that time. Seems we need to change this to utf8mb4. On the other hand there's a WL to rename that to utf8 (and remove the old utf8 impl).

Comment: Hi @NicolasBouvrette & MikeLischke 
is there any documented information about this behaviour?

Comment: Second hit in DuckDuckGo: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html. Searching helps!

Comment: @MikeLischke Found it at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-new.html


"When opening connections, MySQL Workbench automatically sets the client character set to utf8. Manually changing the client character set, such as using SET NAMES ..., may cause MySQL Workbench to not correctly display the characters."


I have activated the "general log" & checked that Workbench executes "SET CHARACTER SET utf8; SET NAMES utf8;" when creating a connection.


And i can't see where i can force a "SET NAMES utf8mb4;", so i do it manually

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look at the `GLOBAL` variables

```
show global variables like 'char%';
```

You can find the file that workbench is using by going to `Edit connection`, and use tab `System Profile`.

Link with screenshot: [Is the file "my.ini" in the wrong place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262381/is-the-file-my-ini-in-the-wrong-place/23262761#23262761)

Comment: I can't edit this tab. All options lock. Maybe it's because remote connection?

Comment: Yes, if its remote you must have server access to changes this. Sorry I didnt think about that....